# Is there an equivalent to KnockoutJs' isObservable in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I'm running through some samples on Asp.net Web Api 2 and the project I will eventually be working on is going to utilise AngularJs. A couple of the data-binding scenarios I'm working on will have angular's `$watch` implemented and as I understand it, having the `deep` flag set to true on this function will notify of new and old values, but not at the property level - only at the array object level. The ultimate goal is to be able to isolate a property change and send this change as a `PATCH` request to Web Api rather than send the entire object as a PUT request.

The sample I have is currently using knockoutJs and the approach has a model that represents the data where the property values that need to be watched are set as `observable(propName)`. My question is basically whether or not I can convert the following knockoutJs code to something similar in Angular:

```
  self.watchModel = function (model, callback) {
    for (var key in model) {
      if (model.hasOwnProperty(key) && ko.isObservable(model[key])) {
        self.subscribeToProperty(model, key, function (key, val) {
          callback(model, key, val);
        });
      }
    }
  }

  self.subscribeToProperty = function (model, key, callback) {
    model[key].subscribe(function (val) {
      callback(key, val);
    });
  }
```

with the model looking something similar to the following:

```
var obsEmployee = {
    Id: employee.Id,
    Name: ko.observable(employee.Name),
    Email: ko.observable(employee.Email),
    Salary: ko.observable(employee.Salary),
  }
```

I'm sure that there's either an equivalent method available in Angular, or the difference in implementation is significant enough that there is another approach.

Comment: Absolutely! but can you extend `$watch('name', listener(), deep?)` to pass back which specific item has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

There is not. Angular uses dirty checking instead of a subscription/notification framework. Thus, every observed variable is observable. See here for more: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: That much is apparent, but does the dirty checking aspect expose enough to track down which property within the array object has changed?